# Renaming file on Amazon S3 using rename()

Tags: php

How to rename the file using PHP(in linux).
I am using rename(oldfile,newfile), but not working.

```
rename("s3://mydata/$md5_userid/temp_$id.html","s3://mydata/$md5_userid/$iRow_id.html");
```

Comment: Do you have permission to rename the file?

Comment: Are you sure the first argument exists? `file_exists($path) == TRUE` ?

Comment: After update: `s3://` is not really a normal file. I suppose you're using [`Services_Amazon_S3`](https://pear.php.net/package/Services_Amazon_S3)?

Comment: Given the ACL to bucket while creating in amazon s3. I want to rename the file in the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a [stream wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) for Amazon S3.

It's up to the individual, custom wrapper code to implement [rename functionality](https://www.php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.rename.php).  If your wrapper isn't doing the rename, then either the code it's using is buggy, or it doesn't implement that functionality and either isn't reporting it, *or* you aren't checking the return code from the `rename` function call and it's returning false to signify failure.

You will probably need to actually use the *normal* S3 API to perform your file rename.  If the function is actually returning true, you should file a bug with the people that provided the stream wrapper library.

Edit: If you *are* using PEAR's Services_Amazon_S3 as suggested in the comments, then [the stream wrapper it provides *does* do `rename`](https://github.com/pear/Services_Amazon_S3/blob/c3a4bbf23d83730bb391e111cbe01cd409020d68/Services/Amazon/S3/Stream.php#L569) using the `rename` method starting at about line 570.

Edit2: After examining the code further, if there *are* failures, you will see *warnings* emitted from the stream wrapper.  Perhaps you don't have `error_reporting` cranked up all the way to `-1`?

Comment: Yes.i am using stream wrapper. can u please give me the code(how to rename the files in bucket)

Comment: @user, I will not "give you the code" -- you are either discarding the return value or otherwise have an error in your own `rename` call.  Is the return value true, or false?  If it's returning false, then the rename failed at the S3 level.  If it's returning true, then S3 says the rename worked.

Comment: @Charles the link you provided is broken

Comment: @tq, fixed.  It's irksome that they did not redirect their svn repo viewer to the new canonical file locations on github.